# Show $a^2+b^2+c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {3}$ if $a, b, c$ are *not* multiples of $3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I was given the following problem:

> Show $a^2+b^2+c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {3}$ if $a, b, c$ are *not* multiples of $3$.

I would like *a.* verification of my proof (I self-study); *b.* alternative proofs, to enrich my appreciation of the problem. Here's what I did.

---

> $\text{Lemma (demonstration skipped)} :$ $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}| a \equiv b \pmod{m} \implies a^j \equiv b^j \pmod{m}$.

> $\text{Consideration :}$ I will use the $\binom{a}{b}$ notation to refer to the number of *multisets* of size $b$ that can be drawn out of $a$ elements; *i.e.*, the number of collections *with repetition* but *without order*. This is due to the lack of a proper "\multiset" format in LaTex as provided in the site.

$\text{Solution}$. It is trivial to say

$$\begin{align}
a &\equiv r_1 \pmod{3}\\
b &\equiv r_2\pmod{3}\\
c &\equiv r_3\pmod{3}
\end{align}$$

where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the remainders of $a, b, c$ respectively in the division by $3$.

$I$. Let $S$ be the set of possible values of $r_i$. Because $3\nmid a, \space 3\nmid b, \space 3\nmid c$ we have $S=\{1, 2\}$.

$II.$ There are $2^3=8$ ways to draw $3$ elements of $S$. Since addition is conmutative, their ordering is irrelevant and therefore we have $\binom{2}{3}=\frac{4!}{3!}=4$ possible sums of the form $r_1+r_2+r_3$, with the same principle applying to $r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2$.

$III$. Let $S'$ be the set of the possible results of the sum $r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2$. These possible sums, as is easy to manually compute, are $S'= \{3, 6, 9, 12\}$, where $\forall s \in S' | s=3m, m\in\mathbb{Z}.$ It then follows

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \equiv r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2 \equiv0 \pmod{3}$$

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks correct, but you can make it shorter by showing that if x is not a multiple of 3 then $x^2 \equiv 1  (\mod 3)$.

Comment: I don't think we need to go into any of that combinatorial details.  It'd be enough for *anyone* to simple state that as the congruency classes mod 3 that are not equivalent to $0$ are $1$ and $2$ the possible values, without regard to order are $1^2 +1^2 + 1^2$ or $1^2 + 1^2 +2^2$ or $1^2 + 2^2 + 2^2$ or $2^2 + 2^2 + 2^2$,. You *don't* need to go into any more detail than that. (And by the way, we don't need to refer to remainders any more.  The point of equivalence classes is that we can refer to the classes directly.)

Comment: I understand your first point. However, I did not understand the last bit: "we don't need to refer to remainders anymore. The point of..." etc. It's probably because I'm a self-studying begginer. What did you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not wrong but simply observe that for any $a$ such that $a \not \equiv 0$ mod $3$, then we have that $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod $3$. This is easy enough to prove and follows from your lemma for instance.

Then $x^2, y^2, z^2 \equiv 1$ mod $3$ each, and so $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \equiv 0 $ mod $3$.

Comment: Oh damn Nice solution

Comment: So much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).